# Reducing Strength of Phosphorus Oxoacids

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

My chemistry textbook suggests that "acids which contain a P-H bond have strong reducing properties". Both hypophosphorous acid (H3PO2) and pyrophosphorous acid (H4P2O5) contain two P-H bonds; a P-O-P bond is present additionally in pyrophosphorous acid (as in the figures below). 
Which of these two turns out to be a stronger reducing agent, and why? Or do they have equal reducing properties?

[image: Hypophosphorous Acid]
[image: Pyrophosphorous Acid]

Comment: IMHO, pyrophosphorous acid has comparable reducting properties as phosphorous acid, not as hypophosphorous acid.

Comment: @Poutnik Phosphorous acid has three OH groups, while pyrophosphorous acid has two. Phosphorous acid is a stronger reducing agent in general, hence? (I understand the reducing strength will change in acidic, neutral and basic media)

Comment: AFAIK, phosphoric acid had 3 OH groups, phosphorous acids has 2 OH and 1 H.

Comment: IMHO, condensation of acids does not affect reduction ability much. What does affect it is number of H on P.

Comment: @Poutnik Yeah, 2 OH's (was confused about phosphorous as phosphonic acid). Having one H, you say phosphorous acid doesn't compare well with phosphinic acid as a reducing agent, which has 2 H's (ie phosphinic acid is weaker). Is this somewhat backed by exp. evidence?

Comment: I guess phosphinic=hypophosphorous to keep constant naming within the question.In my knowledge, hypophosphorous acid is stronger reducting agens than phosphorous acid.

Comment: @Poutnik And the relative reducing strengths of hypophosphorous and pyrophosphorous acids?

Comment: the best is to find and compare redox potentials. But they may not be available for Pyro versions.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_%28data_page%29  -0.499V versus -0.276V